# What is the meaning of 'rant' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> As of publication, however, he has not reached the next stage of the tech bro homeless **rant** cycle. --[*The Guardian*](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/feb/17/san-francisco-tech-open-letter-i-dont-want-to-see-homeless-riff-raff), 2/17/16

I tried to look up the word and found that *rant* means "talking nonsense."

Please explain to me the meaning of the sentence and what *rant* means in it.

Comment: Or it could mean "tirade".

Comment: IMHO, this *rant* means exactly what dictionaries say it means. The more difficult part (which you also ask about in the question) is the meaning of the sentence, which we would need the context to be able to understand. (Thanks go to StoneyB for the link to the article!)

Comment: This question should be reopened because the OP did attempt to look up the word himself. The policy referred to in the reason given above explains that the "dictionary" close reason does not apply when learners need help with or after performing such research.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to look up words in a learner's dictionary.

One is [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/).

It says that to rant is

> : to talk loudly and in a way that shows anger : to complain in a way that is unreasonable

The sentence means:

So far, he did not complain even more strongly, like other technology guys in San Francisco are doing.

The sentence appears in [San Francisco tech worker: 'I don't want to see homeless riff-raff'](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/feb/17/san-francisco-tech-open-letter-i-dont-want-to-see-homeless-riff-raff).

Answer (score -3):

Rant means shouting in an angry and boorish manner about something that heavily bothers the speaker.

The sentence above cannot be parsed, and therefore, as it stands, it has no meaning.

You can start a rant about my answer if you like. [Practical Education]

Comment: What do you mean "it cannot be parsed"?  It's very jargonish, and obviously relies on a lot of context, but it's perfectly grammatical.  As of *event-time*, he has not *transitive-verb* *object* *prepositional-phrase*.  The transitive verb here is "reached", and the object he has reached is "the next stage", and the prepositional phrase is "of the tech bro homeless rant cycle", where "TBHRC" is a noun phrase: a cycle, of the type "tech bro" and "homeless".